# Create quarterly interval with timex and elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to create quarterly intervals similar to how I create monthly intervals with this code

```
[from: start_date, until: end_date, right_open: false]
|> Timex.Interval.new()
|> Timex.Interval.with_step([months: 1])
|> Enum.map(&Timex.format!(&1, "%Y-%m", :strftime))
```

The intervals should be Jan-Mar Q1, Apr-Jun Q2, Jul-Sep Q3, Oct-Dec Q4. I could accomplish this by rounding the month down to the first date of the quarter and increment by three months, but I am wondering if there is built in functionality to do quarters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want the quarters from the beggining of the provided year, you could do this:

```
Timex.Interval.new(from: Timex.beginning_of_year(provided_date),
                   until: [years: 1],
                   right_open: false,
                   step: [months: 3])
|> Enum.map(&Timex.format!(&1, "%Y-%m", :strftime))
```

(this returns `["2018-01", "2018-04", "2018-07", "2018-10"]`)

BTW you don't actually need to use `with_step/2` in your original line. You only need to use that function when you're changing the original step. You can declare the step directly in `new/1` like I've done in the above example.

While Timex won't automatically build quarter intervals, it does have a way to get the quarter that a date belongs to. You could do this if you need to start from the current quarter:

```
Timex.Interval.new(from: Timex.beginning_of_quarter(provided_date),
               until: [years: 1],
               right_open: false,
               step: [months: 3])
|> Enum.map(&Timex.format!(&1, "%Y-%m", :strftime))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't start from the beginning of the year, I need to start from the quarter the start_date is in. So, looks like I will need to get current quarter and increment from there. Thanks for the tip on with_step.

Comment: @MichaelStClair please check the updated answer. While Timex doesn't have a way to build quarter intervals it does have a way to get the current quarter for a provided date

Comment: Thanks for the help, that is cleaner than using ceil and creating a new date

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mario he helped simplify the code. Here is the finished code I ended up with

```
def periods(start_date, end_date, "quarter") do
  start_date = Timex.beginning_of_quarter(start_date)
  [from: start_date, until: end_date, right_open: false, step: [months: 3]]
  |> Interval.new
  |> Enum.map(&calculate_quarter(&1))
end

def calculate_quarter(date), do: "Q#{Timex.quarter(date)} #{Timex.format!(date, "%Y", :strftime)}"
```

Comment: BTW you can clean up your `calculate_quarter/1` function with `Timex.quarter/1` which returns the quarter for that date. `"Q#{Timex.quarter(date)} #{Timex.format!(date, "%Y", :strftime)}"`

Comment: also just FYI, `calculate_quarter/1` is never going to get anything other that months 1, 4, 7, and 10 btw, since you're feeding it quarterly intervals

Comment: I am also using it for other dates that won't be from the interval to see what quarter they go in. Thanks for the quarter function!